# MongoDB instance failure testing

Tags: ruby, mongodb, testing

I am working on [Ruby MongoDB Client on Eventmachine](https://github.com/fl00r/monga) and I was wondering how to test mongo instance failure, replica sets voting (primary failure) and other such kind of stuff.

In example. Client should establish connections to Replica Set. Then primary failed and client should find next primary and redirect all queries there.

Maybe there is mongodb command to pause/resume instance. Or should I fork processes and sigstop/sigcont (but this will be OS dependent solution).

**UPD**

Just looked how `mongodb-ruby-driver` do it job, going to do the same
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/test/tools/mongo_config.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have implemented fake Mongodb Server that binds to required port, answers with fake replies to queries. Also it replies on "isMaster" query. So you can stop primary/secondary any time, you could fire voting who will be next primary, etc. It's look the very best choice because it is about 100 lines of code and works perfectly on any OS. :)

https://github.com/fl00r/monga/blob/master/spec/helpers/mongodb.rb

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some advice based on what I've done with testing Mongo replica sets, but I'm afraid it's fairly specific to hosting nodes in the cloud. Still maybe you can take something away from it.

Assuming you have a replica set up:

1. Make sure all nodes have the same priority. Write a client that does slow reads against the replica set (making sure all three machines are represented in your client config). Slow reads meaning write a big query and then iterate slowly over the cursor. Go ahead and take the primary offline and see what happens. You can tail the log files for the other nodes to watch them vote for a new primary.
2. If you're using host names for each node, run a slow running query and then stop/start a node such that the host name gets a new IP address. We've found the Mongo client does *not* refresh the DNS cache and you're stuck with an old IP address.  (This is for the Java client - we've filed a Jira bug).
3. Notice that if you reboot all nodes in the replica set the primary is shifted around. Sometimes it will be node 1, sometimes node 2, etc. This assumes the priority for all nodes are the same. Does your client handle this well? We used to have issues because we had hard coded one node for writes and suddenly all writes would fail.
4. Write a tool to simulate continuous writes and then start taking nodes offline, kill the primary, restart a machine with a new IP etc. Are you going to drop any writes?
5. There is no command I know of to pause/resume instances other than just stopping mongod. I like powering machines down to test personally.

Comment: Hi ryan, thank you for your response! But I asked about simulating failing of instances in my functional/unit tests so anybody who will run tests will be satisfied in any OS. And not mocking. Anyway all you wrote is very useful for me now!

Comment: Oh sorry. I would check out embedded Mongo for simulating in unit/functional tests. https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de

Comment: Hm. Embededmongo looks promising! Thanks a lot